# Broadcast receiver is not called on real devices

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-10.0

I have updated target version from Android 8 to Android 10 after that I am facing an issue that broadcast receiver is not being called on devices(I have tested on Samsung s9(Pie), Mi Note 5(Oreo)) accept Google Pixel 2  XL device(Android 10) but it's working fine on Genymotion Samsung s9 emulator or any emulator. Can anybody tell what could be the possible issue?

There is Service called SipService inside that it registering the Intent filters and  we trigger one of the Intent filter from one of the activity. Some codes are as below.

**ACtivity**

inside onCreate() method

```
 registerReceiver(registrationStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(SipManager.ACTION_SIP_REGISTRATION_CHANGED));
        bindService(new Intent(mContext, SipService.class), connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

And after some Webservice  calls and operation we are calling one of the registered Intent Filter as below.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(SipManager.ACTION_SIP_REQUEST_RESTART);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
```

**Inside SipService class**

```
private void registerBroadcasts() {
        // Register own broadcast receiver
        if (deviceStateReceiver == null) {
            IntentFilter intentfilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentfilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
            intentfilter.addAction(SipManager.ACTION_SIP_ACCOUNT_CHANGED);
            intentfilter.addAction(SipManager.ACTION_SIP_ACCOUNT_DELETED);
            intentfilter.addAction(SipManager.ACTION_SIP_CAN_BE_STOPPED);
            intentfilter.addAction(SipManager.ACTION_SIP_REQUEST_RESTART);
            intentfilter.addAction(DynamicReceiver4.ACTION_VPN_CONNECTIVITY);
            if (Compatibility.isCompatible(5)) {
                deviceStateReceiver = new DynamicReceiver5(this);
            } else {
                deviceStateReceiver = new DynamicReceiver4(this);
            }
            registerReceiver(deviceStateReceiver, intentfilter);
            deviceStateReceiver.startMonitoring();
        }
}
```

**Receiver Class**

```
public class DynamicReceiver4 extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String THIS_FILE = "DynamicReceiver";


    // Comes from android.net.vpn.VpnManager.java
    // Action for broadcasting a connectivity state.
    public static final String ACTION_VPN_CONNECTIVITY = "vpn.connectivity";
    /** Key to the connectivity state of a connectivity broadcast event. */
    public static final String BROADCAST_CONNECTION_STATE = "connection_state";

    private SipService service;


    // Store current state
    private String mNetworkType;
    private boolean mConnected = false;
    private String mRoutes = "";

    private boolean hasStartedWifi = false;


    private Timer pollingTimer;


    /**
     * Check if the intent received is a sticky broadcast one 
     * A compat way
     * @param it intent received
     * @return true if it's an initial sticky broadcast
     */
    public boolean compatIsInitialStickyBroadcast(Intent it) {
        if(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(it.getAction())) {
            if(!hasStartedWifi) {
                hasStartedWifi = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public DynamicReceiver4(SipService aService) {
        service = aService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        // Run the handler in SipServiceExecutor to be protected by wake lock
        service.getExecutor().execute(new SipService.SipRunnable()  {
            public void doRun() throws SipService.SameThreadException {
                onReceiveInternal(context, intent, compatIsInitialStickyBroadcast(intent));
            }
        });
    }



    /**
     * Internal receiver that will run on sip executor thread
     * @param context Application context
     * @param intent Intent received
     * @throws SameThreadException
     */
    private void onReceiveInternal(Context context, Intent intent, boolean isSticky) throws SipService.SameThreadException {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(THIS_FILE, "Internal receive " + action);
        if (action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            ConnectivityManager cm =
                    (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            onConnectivityChanged(activeNetwork, isSticky);
        } else if (action.equals(SipManager.ACTION_SIP_ACCOUNT_CHANGED)) {
            final long accountId = intent.getLongExtra(SipProfile.FIELD_ID, SipProfile.INVALID_ID);
            // Should that be threaded?
            if (accountId != SipProfile.INVALID_ID) {
                final SipProfile account = service.getAccount(accountId);
                if (account != null) {
                    Log.d(THIS_FILE, "Enqueue set account registration");
                    service.setAccountRegistration(account, account.active ? 1 : 0, true);
                }
            }
        } else if (action.equals(SipManager.ACTION_SIP_ACCOUNT_DELETED)){
            final long accountId = intent.getLongExtra(SipProfile.FIELD_ID, SipProfile.INVALID_ID);
            if(accountId != SipProfile.INVALID_ID) {
                final SipProfile fakeProfile = new SipProfile();
                fakeProfile.id = accountId;
                service.setAccountRegistration(fakeProfile, 0, true);
            }
        } else if (action.equals(SipManager.ACTION_SIP_CAN_BE_STOPPED)) {
            service.cleanStop();
        } else if (action.equals(SipManager.ACTION_SIP_REQUEST_RESTART)){
            service.restartSipStack();
        } else if(action.equals(ACTION_VPN_CONNECTIVITY)) {
            onConnectivityChanged(null, isSticky);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think anyone can help without any piece of code being shown along with the question

Comment: Please share your code or tell us what is your goal?

Comment: @VivekMishra kindly check

Comment: Implicit broadcasts are largely banned on Android 8.0 and higher: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html

Comment: @CommonsWare it was working fine on API level 27 now causing issue when I am targeting API 29.

Comment: Actually, My bad it was basically ABI(Application Binary Interface) issue that causing issue in bit 64 devices.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, My bad it was basically ABI(Application Binary Interface) issue that causing the issue in bit 64 devices.

Comment: Can you please elaborate upon this answer? I am facing a similar issue on a Pixel 4 device, running Android 29.

Comment: Actually, In my application, I have used some .so files which were causing the issue after targeting API 29. @BrianJ.Roberts

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my apk, one pixel4 is receiving ACL_CONNECTED and ACL_DISCONNECTED from our .aar's manifest-registered implicit broadcast receiver in one apk that consumes this aar as expected. But in another app that consumes this same .aar, the broadcast is not received. On other phones this is not issue, even with the same builds, but we are struggling to root cause. @DjP